# uploading .csv file from local to django Admin

Tags: python, django, csv

I am stuck and confused trying to work out an issue (adding a button on Django/Admin, like in the photo below) with my exercise and I don't understand what's wrong, I can't figure it out on my own. I want to create an uploader of .csv file on Django admin. 
Therefore I've created the following admin.py :

```
import csv
from io import TextIOWrapper
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.urls import path
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .models import Alimenti, Genere


class CsvImportForm(forms.Form):
    csv_file = forms.FileField()

@admin.register(Alimenti)
class AlimentiAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, CsvImportForm):
    list_display = (
        "alimento", 
        "codice_alimento", 
        "parte_edibile", 
        "energia_kj", 
        "energia_ricalcolata_con_fibra_kj", 
        "energia_ricalcolata_kcal", 
        "energia_ricalcolata_con_fibra_kcal", 
        "proteine_totali_gr", 
        "proteine_animali_gr", 
        "proteine_vegetali_gr", 
        "lipidi_totali_gr", 
        "lipidi_animali_gr", 
        "lipidi_vegetali_gr", 
        "colesterolo_mg", 
    )

    change_list_template = "admin/change_list.html"

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('Import CSV/', self.import_csv),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def import_csv(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            csv_file = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES["csv_file"].file, encoding='utf-8')
            reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

            # create Alimenti object from passed in data
            for row in reader:
                Alimenti.objects.get_or_create(
                    alimento=row[0],
                    codice_alimento=row[1],
                    parte_edibile=row[2],
                    energia_kj=row[3].replace(",",'.'),
                    energia_ricalcolata_con_fibra_kj=row[4].replace(",",'.'),
                    energia_ricalcolata_kcal=row[5].replace(",",'.'),
                    energia_ricalcolata_con_fibra_kcal=row[6].replace(",",'.'),
                    proteine_totali_gr=row[7].replace(",",'.'),
                    proteine_animali_gr=row[8].replace(",",'.'),
                    proteine_vegetali_gr=row[9].replace(",",'.'),
                    lipidi_totali_gr=row[10].replace(",",'.'),
                    lipidi_animali_gr=row[11].replace(",",'.'),
                    lipidi_vegetali_gr=row[12].replace(",",'.'),
                    colesterolo_mg=row[13].replace(",",'.'),
                    )

            self.message_user(request, "Il file csv è stato importato correttamente")
            return redirect("admin/change_list")
        form = CsvImportForm()
        payload = {"form": form}
        return render(
            request, "admin/csv_form.html", payload
        )



class CsvImportForm(forms.Form):
    csv_files = forms.FileField()

@admin.register(Genere)
class GenereAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, CsvImportForm):
    list_display = (
        "ALIMENTO", 
        "CODICE_MERCEOLOGICO", 
        "GRUPPO_MERCEOLOGICO"
    )

    change_list_template = "admin/change_list.html"

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('Import CSV/', self.import_csv),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def import_csv(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            csv_files = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES["csv_files"].file, encoding='utf-8')
            roader = csv.reader(csv_files)

            # create Genere object from passed in data
            for rew in roader:
                Genere.objects.get_or_create(
                    ALIMENTO = rew[0],
                    CODICE_MERCEOLOGICO = rew[1],
                    GRUPPO_MERCEOLOGICO = rew[2]
                )

            self.message_user(request, "Il file csv è stato importato correttamente")
            return redirect("admin/change_list")
        form = CsvImportForm()
        payload = {"form": form}
        return render(
            request, "admin/csv_form.html", payload
        )
```

[image]

I don't know if the second decorator here above it is correct because when I run the code I receive a traceback error: errorIndex ..list out of range...

```
@admin.register(Genere)
    class GenereAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, CsvImportForm):
        list_display = (
            "ALIMENTO", 
            "CODICE_MERCEOLOGICO", 
            "GRUPPO_MERCEOLOGICO"
        )

        change_list_template = "admin/change_list.html"

        def get_urls(self):
            urls = super().get_urls()
            my_urls = [
                path('Import CSV/', self.import_csv),
            ]
            return my_urls + urls

        def import_csv(self, request):
            if request.method == "POST":
                csv_files = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES["csv_files"].file, encoding='utf-8')
                roader = csv.reader(csv_files)

                # create Genere object from passed in data
                for rew in roader:
                    Genere.objects.get_or_create(
                        ALIMENTO = rew[0],
                        CODICE_MERCEOLOGICO = rew[1],
                        GRUPPO_MERCEOLOGICO = rew[2]
                    )

                self.message_user(request, "Il file csv è stato importato correttamente")
                return redirect("admin/change_list")
            form = CsvImportForm()
            payload = {"form": form}
            return render(
                request, "admin/csv_form.html", payload
            )
```

I can't find similar question on the web, so I've decided to ask for help. What am I missing here? What's wrong?

This is the full traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Massimo\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Massimo\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Massimo\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Massimo\Documents\GitHub\Django\nutrythm\superfood\admin.py" in import_csv
  263.                     CODICE_MERCEOLOGICO = rew[1],

Exception Type: IndexError at /admin/superfood/genere/Import CSV/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Thanks in advance for any advice,
Massman

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Try django import export. Hope this is what you're trying.

Comment: I don't know if it is reinventing the wheel case. I would simply create a button into admin page where it is possible to upload a .csv file.
Using the first decorator it works perfectly, when I add the second decorator it doesn't and produce the errorIndex. I am confused at that point.

Comment: The file I am uploading generate an IndexError (out of range), as if I'd look for a value not included into the list. But in fact I am importing and not opening. The .csv file has the same structure as indicate into the form.py, admin.py and model.py. 
What don't I understand?

Comment: Could you share your csv file here? Or please try this , https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export

Comment: Your question did open my eyes. When I was charging the .csv file here, I saw the delimiter was ";" instead of comma :s , anyway your hint was enough to help me, thank you!